# Learning backbone.js. Am I handling collections correctly?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I come from a ruby/rails background, so I am having some trouble wrapping my mind around the backbone course exercises on UDEMY. Can someone tell me if I am making any errors, and how to fix them if so? This exercise was about collections and I need the output to be the console.logs

```
var Vehicle = Backbone.Model.extend({

default: {
    registrationNumber: "XXX-XXX", 
    color: "beige"
}

urlRoot: "/api/vehicle",

start: function(){
    console.log("Vehicle started");
}
});

var Vehicles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Vehicle,

url:"api/vehicles"
});

var vehicles = new Vehicles([
new Vehicle({car1: {registrationNumber = "XLI887", color = "Blue"} }),
new Vehicle({car2: {registrationNumber = "ZNP123", color = "Blue"}}),
new Vehicle({car3: {registrationNumber = "XUV456", color = "Grey"}})
]);

var blueCars = vehicles.where({ color: "Blue"});
 var specificRegistration = vehicles.where({ registrationNumber:"XLI887"});

console.log("blue cars:", blueCars);
console.log("Registration #:", specificRegistration);


console.log("to JSON:", vehicles.toJSON());
```

[image: Code Below:]

Comment: It would be a little easier to provide tips on your code if you provided your code in text rather than as a screenshot. =)

Comment: I am fairly new to stackoverflow. Is there a shortcut to indent entire blocks of code 4 spaces on the site? If so I will edit...

Comment: you could add indent in the editor and paste from it to stackoverflow

Comment: ahhh I've always wondered about this, and now I know to press the code button AFTER highlighting the code. Sorry for dumb questions everyone has to start somewhere....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong

```
new Vehicle({car1: {registrationNumber = "XLI887", color = "Blue" }})
```

and should be replaced with

```
new Vehicle({registrationNumber: "XLI887", color: "Blue" })
```

or event with this

```
{registrationNumber: "XLI887", color: "Blue" }
```

so `Collection` may accept either array of `Model`s or just array of objects with data, which will be passed to the model constructor used in collection.

You can also use [Collection#findWhere](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) to return just a first found model instead of array of models like in `where`

Also I found you forgot to add coma after `default` section

```
default: {
    registrationNumber: "XXX-XXX", 
    color: "beige"
}, // here should be a coma
```

Comment: so the car1 is unnecessary? Will it execute if I make these changes? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Here is a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0a99trkr/ you can open console and run it to see results